# Yarn install - Couldn't find any version "react-is" that matches [Latest version]

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, package.json

This error happened when I ran `yarn install` today. I solved it by manually picking the last older version which is `18.8.5`. But when I ran it in Jenkins, I was unable to manually pick like that.

I can't find this dependency in `package.json`, so it seem that `react-is` is the sub-dependency of some packages that use version `16.8.6`.

I tried to use `yarn resolutions` to force it to `18.6.5` but many package use react-is with many difference version so it causes other errors.

Any way to solve an issue like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem. My nexus3 repository has the issue about caching so it do not update lastest version of `react-is`, so when I install, yarn can't find that version and crash the build.
I solved this issue by remove the caching of nexus3, it's done : )

Answer (score 3):

I solved the error below in my system with `yarn cache clean`:

> error Couldn't find match for
>   "53c351b16a1130c959bb54e3d52df290dc9aa64f" in refs/...

The issue is most likely caused by a git rebase and a force push.